# Why can I inject request-scoped beans in the absence of a request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

If I try to inject a request-scoped bean into a singleton-scoped one, that  fails because

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

as it should.

(See at the end of this post for code examples)

I know of three ways to get below test to turn green:

1. change the scope of the `UsingBean`
2. method injection
3. scoped proxies

([1] is more of a hack than a solution and likely to cause issues further down the line, but it *does* turn the test green. :P)

And while I do understand the idea behind these three options, I don't get *why* they work at all.

I mean, even if I change the scope to "session" in [1], I still have neither session nor request when I instantiate the `UsingBean`.

As for [2] and [3], they avoid getting an instance at startup, but I still don't have a request when they actually DO fetch an instance.

And yet the test doesn't fail. Why?

***CODE EXAMPLE***

Let's say I have a request-scoped bean

```
@Repository
@Scope("request")
class RequestScopedBean : ScopedBean{
    override fun foo(): String {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}
```

used in a singleton-scoped one

```
@Service
class UsingBean{
    private val scopedBean:ScopedBean

    @Inject
    constructor(scopedBean: ScopedBean) {
        this.scopedBean = scopedBean
    }

    fun foo():String{
        val foo = scopedBean.foo()
        println(foo)
        return foo
    }
}
```

and let's also create a small test for this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
class RequestScopedBeansIT{

    @Inject
    private lateinit var bean : UsingBean

    @Test
    fun canInject(){
        assertThat(bean.foo()).isEqualTo("Hello World")
    }
}
```

**1) change the scope** of the `UsingBean`

```
@Service
@Scope("session")
class UsingBean{
    private val scopedBean:ScopedBean

    @Inject
    constructor(scopedBean: ScopedBean) {
        this.scopedBean = scopedBean
    }

    fun foo():String{
        val foo = scopedBean.foo()
        println(foo)
        return foo
    }
}
```

**2) method injection**

```
@Service
class UsingBean{
    private val scopedBean:ScopedBean
        get() = injectBean()

    fun foo():String{
        val foo = scopedBean.foo()
        println(foo)
        return foo
    }

    @Lookup
    fun injectBean():ScopedBean{
        TODO("will be replaced by spring")
    }
}
```

**3) Scoped Proxy**

```
@Repository
@Scope("request",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class RequestScopedBean : ScopedBean{
    override fun foo(): String {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}
```

or

```
@Repository
@RequestScope
class RequestScopedBean : ScopedBean{
    override fun foo(): String {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}
```

Comment: You do have a request, that is what `@WebAppConfiguration` is taking care of. It binds a `MockServletRequest` etc. to the current executing thread. So yes you do have a request.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you. Want to make an answer out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you might think you don't have a current you request and session you actually do have one.

The `@WebAppConfiguration` is what triggers that. It will activate the [`ServletTestExecutionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/web/ServletTestExecutionListener.html) which will register a thread-bound mocked request and response.

Which explains why the test succeeds as there is a thread-bound request.